# Silverlight: Break on Binding Errors

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

Is there a way to cause Visual Studio to break on binding errors in Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No not yet, I believe that won't be avaliable until Silverlight 5.

Fire Starter Scott Guthrie Key Note:
[Silverlight 5](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Silverlight-Firestarter/Silverlight-Firestarter-2010-Keynote-with-Scott-Guthrie)

Comment: Oh yea, I remember seeing the video on that now.